# Is there a way to tell when KVO starts/ends for a particular value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, key-value-observing

I have some values that are computed over collections, and may or may not be displayed (and thus may or may not have an observer) at any given time.   I would rather not have to track all the members of the collection if nobody is observing my computed values.

Can I tell if anyone is currently observing a value, and can I tell when they start observing?

I know for a given object `foo` I can use `[foo observationInfo]` to get a list of observers with key paths registered with a root at foo, **but** that doesn't automatically get all paths TO foo (in fact it only gets ones registered to observe foo's self key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s not a good idea from the design point of view. If you really insist on not updating the contents when nobody needs them (which could be a legitimate case, for example if the updates are expensive), you can introduce methods to start/stop the updates:

```
- (void) beginUpdatingContents;
- (void) endUpdatingContents;
```

These should be tied to a counter inside the class and if the counter is > 0, you know somebody wants to keep the contents updated. This solution is explicit and therefore better than silent magic with KVO.

Comment: Wait, if the problem was introduced by silent KVO magic, the answer isn't **even more silent KVO magic**?

Comment: There’s a point where there’s simply too much silent KVO magic. With your solution I feel we might be getting near :)

Comment: Well my 1st comment was 85% joke.   The other 15% is that this project was actually intended just to be a iOS and Core Data learning experience for me, so if I code up the "more magic" version and decide it is "too much" magic I'm actually closer to achieving my goals then if I just play it safe.

Comment: In that case you can dig right in, it’s good to discover the KVO limitations. Search for KVO on [Cocoa Builder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/), there’s plenty of great discussion. And let’s see if somebody here comes up with a KVO-based solution to your problem.

Comment: This worked nicely for me.  I would think twice about it in an API for others to consume...   but as no better answers have come up the result of thinking twice may well be "do it this way anyway" :-)

Comment: It’s a design pattern used on several places in Cocoa Touch (if that sounds reassuring). See for example `UIApplication` or `UIDevice`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more magic, how about overriding `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` and `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` and tracking what is still observing you?

The way I've actually done this in the past is by making wrapper objects (I called them bindings) which set up KVO and also register themselves with the target. So, a user would call `MyBinding *binding = [targetObject bindKeyPath:@"foo" ...]` and then later `[binding detach]`. You then have the binding use KVO under the hood and keep a list of themselves so you know when it's empty.